# Error initializing android Sensor Manager

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error

```
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593): Error intializing sensors
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at com.magnusworks.justtic_tac_toe.GameScene.create(GameScene.java:45)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at com.magnusworks.justtic_tac_toe.SceneManager$1.doInBackground(SceneManager.java:37)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at com.magnusworks.justtic_tac_toe.SceneManager$1.doInBackground(SceneManager.java:1)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-26 13:00:47.564: E/GameScene(21593):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**At this location**

```
/*44*/try{
        /*45*/sm = (SensorManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE); //<--- here          
/*46*/  acceleration = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            sm.registerListener(this, acceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
        catch(Exception f){
            Log.e("GameScene", "Error intializing sensors", f);
        }
```

Am I initializing the sensor manager incorrectly?

Comment: Can you please number the lines in the code? That will help

Comment: I added only a few... you should hopefully be able to figure the rest of them out by yourself XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.activity` is `null` in your case.

replace it with:

```
if (this.activity != null) {
    sm = (SensorManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helpped... however it does not fix my problem... I'm not sure while this.activity = null... any idea how to get the context?

Comment: @MagnusCaligo Sorry, I've never programmed for Android, and not even sure what class are you running the code in, and what is this.activity :) I just answered based on my knowledge of basic java

Comment: Can you post more code for your activity. In which method is the try block?

Comment: Never mind XD I just realized, I had a method to initialize a bunch of variables (including activity) and I had never called it hahaha i'm an idiot

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a vulnerable statement:

```
sm = (SensorManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Modify this statement as:

```
sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

When we extend Activity Class in out mainActivity.java class, the method `getSystemService()` get accessible to you. Dont need to write `this.activity.getSystemService();`.